# What is the difference between Bhaava Lagna, Hora lagna, and Ghati lagna?

Tags: vedas, astrology

What is the difference between Bhaava Lagna, Hora lagna, and Ghati lagna?
I am confused about the concepts of Bhaava Lagna, Hora lagna, and Ghati lagna, and I am not sure what their respective purposes are?